# SQL; SELECT, WHERE AND OR

Tags: sql

I need a Query which would return results like this :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE IDtable1 = IDtable2 AND (Column1 like "THIS" OR Column1 Like "THAT")
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT [SALARIE_nom] & " " & [SALARIE_prenom] & " (" & [SALARIE_NNI] & ")" AS Salarié,
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant, 
T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut

FROM 
(T_STATUT_EMPLOI INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_id = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id) LEFT JOIN R_Select_Salarie ON T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni = R_Select_Salarie.SALARIE_NNI

WHERE 
(((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=[Formulaires]![F_COMOB]![ACTION_identifiant_emploi]) 
AND 
((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*valid*")) 
OR 
(((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*décidé*"));
```

It works as I want only when I don't put the :

```
OR 
    (((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*décidé*"))
```

**When I try this** (Regroup the OR part)

```
WHERE 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant=[Formulaires]![F_COMOB]![ACTION_identifiant_emploi]
AND 
(T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut Like "*valid*"
OR 
T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut Like "*décidé*");
```

No results are shown.

**And when I try This**

```
WHERE 
(((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=[Formulaires]![F_COMOB]![ACTION_identifiant_emploi]) 
AND 
((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*valid*")) 
OR 
(((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*décidé*"));
```

It's seem like it didn't take this

```
WHERE 
    (((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=[Formulaires]![F_COMOB]![ACTION_identifiant_emploi])
```

into consideration

Comment: why so many parenthesis? If you start removing them you'll notice that your examples dont match in syntactical sense.

Comment: What DBMS is this? `Like "*valid*"` looks a bit strange, and so does `[SALARIE_nom] & " " ...`. Is the MS Access or what else?

Comment: Yes, It's MS Access

Comment: Ah, then we are far from SQL standard compliant. That also explains the parentheses in the FROM clause. MS Access is so different from other DBMS, that I hope that others will be able to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding opening bracket after the AND in the Where condition and closing bracket before semicolon(;)

Does it return desired result?

```
SELECT [SALARIE_nom] & " " & [SALARIE_prenom] & " (" & [SALARIE_NNI] & ")" AS Salarié,
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant, 
T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut

FROM 
(T_STATUT_EMPLOI INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_id = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id) LEFT JOIN R_Select_Salarie ON T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni = R_Select_Salarie.SALARIE_NNI

WHERE 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant=[Formulaires]![F_COMOB]![ACTION_identifiant_emploi]
AND 
(T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut Like "*valid*"
OR 
T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut Like "*décidé*");
```

Comment: It didn't give the right result

Comment: Please try again, just keep those necessary parenthesis. If you remove unnecessary parenthesis, you'll realized that, you are grouping the first and second where condition instead of the second and third

Comment: I added more detail on results I get each time

Comment: can you provide some sample data and sample desired result?

Comment: Actually Your code is correct and worked. While working on something else I knew what I did wrong earlier. So I retried it now and it is the correct optimal query. Thank you !!!